# How to use ng-repeat with JSON object?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

It doesn't work

**HTML**

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items">
 <p>{{forecasts.list[$index].main.temp}}</p>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
$http({
 method: 'GET',
 url: 'http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?q='+$scope.city +'&units=metric&cnt=3&appid=338d293879598530ec8cef82c5d375d4'
}).then(function (success) {
 console.log("nice");
 $scope.forecasts = success.data;
 }, function (error) {
   console.log("error");
});
```

How to rewrite ng-repeat and use objects from this
[JSON](https://i.stack.imgur.com/605aC.png)

Comment: "It didn’t work” is not an adequate description of the problem. See http://idownvotedbecau.se/itsnotworking/

Answer (score 0):

You have to iterate over the `$scope.forecasts.list` property. I advice you to read how to use `ng-repeat` in the AngularJS documentation.

```
<div ng-repeat="temperatures in forecasts.list">
  <p>{{ temperatures.main.temp }}</p>
</div>
```